# Why is my plant turning white/yellow

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, watering, indoors

It’s winter here in Quebec city, and I feel like my plant is slowly dying. At first I thought it lacked sun, do I putted it on the windows border, but the furnace in just below so it might have dry hot air coming towards it. At least it has the sun now.

Is it a symptom of dry air? or lack of sun? what can I do to revert the dying process here

[image: plant]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain, but it looks like your plant is sitting in water in the outer pot; that is something most plants will not  tolerate and remain healthy, so when you water, always empty out any excess in an exterior pot or tray 30 minutes afterwards. As for sunlight, they don't really appreciate direct sun, especially when they're fairly small - bright daylight is best. They prefer a degree of humidity in the air and should not be placed near heat sources. Water regularly, allowing the soil to dry out slightly between waterings (test by touching the soil with a finger, it should feel just slightly dry to the touch) and when you do water, water thoroughly, and then follow the recommendations above. More info here https://www.thespruce.com/grow-blood-leaf-indoors-1902571

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you will get lots of suggestions, but here is my take on your situation - the plant is an *Iresine herbstii "Aureoreticulata"* so that you can look it up and compare notes. It natively grows in Brazil in warm, high light and high humidity conditions for most of the year. It does not mind being overwatered but not consistently so. In Quebec it is deep winter and the heating system is running hard and fast so unless you have a humidifier and lots of additional light it will be very hard to keep this plant happy. Ideally we want to avoid the temptation to give it lots of water in winter to make up for the low humidity; that just will not work.

So here is what I would do with this plant - I would cut back that main shoot by about half, trim off the dead leaves from the cutting and put it in a small jar of water, half in half out, and then put both the cutting in its jar and the main plant (after clearing up the dead leaf situation and making sure the soil is moist but not wet) in a clear plastic bag and seal it up so that both occupants have lots of air and space. Move this bag with plants to an east or west bright light window. Leave the whole package alone until spring, even if you see droplets of water on the inside of the clear bag. Basically we have created a terrarium for it to enjoy humid conditions in winter where it will not need to be watered or fed.

The little cutting should start to produce roots in the spring and can be moved to a pot of regular potting soil. Voilà maintenant deux belles plantes.